# NTLM Authorization in Perl

Tags: perl, winapi, ntlm, sspi

I am trying to implement NTLM authorisation for a web server written in Perl (or perhaps an XS module). My understanding is that it should work in the following way:

```
c -> s: GET
s -> c: 401, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
c -> s: GET, Authorization: NTLM [Type1 Message]
s -> c: 401, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM [Type2 Message]
c -> s: GET, Authorization: NTLM [Type3 Message]

IF s.Check([Type3 Message]):
  s -> c: 200
ELSE:
  s -> c: 401
```

To generate the Type3 message I have used both [Authen::Perl::NTLM](http://search.cpan.org/~umvue/Authen-Perl-NTLM-0.12/lib/Authen/Perl/NTLM.pm) and [Authen::NTLM::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Authen-NTLM-HTTP-0.33/lib/Authen/NTLM/HTTP.pm), both of these seem to generate the messages perfectly fine, however, they offer no functionality to check the Type3 Message.

My next step has been to try and use [Win32::IntAuth](http://search.cpan.org/~tomk/Win32-IntAuth-0.20/lib/Win32/IntAuth.pm) to authenticate the NTLM token. **This** is where I have been running in to trouble, the developer and other snippets of information found searching say that this module should be able to Authenticate an NTLM binary token.

The module wraps around some Win32 API calls, namely AcquireCredntialsHandle, AcceptSecurityContext, CompleteAuthToken and ImpersonateSecurityContext.

Unfortunately all my attempts to authenticate the NTLM token have failed at AcceptSecurityContext with either **SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN** or **SEC_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY** leading me to suggest my NTLM token isn't correct. Below is some snippets of code to help show my methods.

```
# other code
...
if (not defined $headers->header('Authorization')) {
    initHandshake($response); 
} else { 
    my $authHeader = $headers->header('Authorization');
    if ($authHeader =~ m/^NTLM\s(.+)$/i) { 
        my $message = $1;
        if (length($message) == 56) {
            handleType1($response, $message);
        } else {
            handleType3($response, $message);
        }
    } else {
        printf "ERROR - Unable to pull out an NTLM message.\n";
        print $authHeader . "\n";
    }
} 
... 
sub handleType3 {
    my $response = shift();
    my $message = shift();
    print "handleType3 - ", $message, "\n";
    my $auth = Win32::IntAuth->new(debug => 1);
    my $token = $auth->get_token_upn(decode_base64($message)) or die 
                           "Couldn'timpersonate user, ", $auth->last_err_txt();
    print "Hurrargh. User ", $auth->get_username(), " authed!\n";
    $response->status(200);
} 
..
```

The full code can be viewed here: http://codepad.org/cpMWnFru

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get this working by bastardizing `Win32::IntAuth` (which I believe has a bug in it). Essentially I wasn't holding the partial context created during the creation of the Type 2 token, this and the fact that there was an error in `Win32::IntAuth`:

```
my $buf_size     = 4096;
my $sec_inbuf    = pack("L L P$buf_size", $buf_size, SECBUFFER_TOKEN, $token);
```

This was causing a token error as it wasn't the correct length of the token, therefore:

```
my $sec_inbuf    = pack("L L P" . length($token), length($token), SECBUFFER_TOKEN, $token);
```

Produced the correct results.

The previous code was changed to:

```
...
sub handleType1 {
    my $response = shift();
    my $message = shift();                               
    print "handleType1 - |", ${$message}, "|\n";
    my $challenge = acceptSecurityContext(${$message});
    ${$response}->status(401);
    ${$response}->header("WWW-Authenticate" => "NTLM " . $challenge);
}
...
sub handleType3 {
    my $response = shift();               
    my $message = shift();
    print "handleType3 - ", ${$message}, "\n";
    if (acceptSecurityContext(${$message})) {
        ${$response}->status(200);
    } else {
        ${$response}->status(401);
    }
}
...
```

acceptSecurityContext is a function that follows this pseudoish code:

```
credentials = Win32->AcquireCredentialsHandle(...)
challenge = Win32->AcceptSecurityContext(credentials, token, globalCtx ? globalCtx : 0, ...)
```